# Why Unicode characters are not displayed properly in terminal with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, unicode

I've written a small C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    wprintf(L"%s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8"));
    wchar_t chr = L'┐';
    wprintf(L"%c\n", chr);
}
```

Why doesn't this print the character `┐` ?

Instead it prints gibberish. [image: unicodetest]

I've checked:

- tried compiling without setlocale, same result
- the terminal itself can print the character, I can copy-paste it to terminal from text-editor, it's gnome-terminal on Ubuntu
- GCC version is 4.8.2

Comment: In addition to the answer below regarding the proper `printf` format specifier, which appears to be the correct answer based on your output, you should also ensure that your source file is encoded using UTF-8 rather than something like ISO-8859-15. That sort of thing is why it's better to use `L'\u2510'` rather than `L'┐'`.

Comment: With the correct format specifier the locale did make a difference, without it the these box-characters are falling back to their ASCII equivalent e.g. `+`, `-` and `|`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wprintf` is a version of `printf` which takes a wide string as its format string, but otherwise behaves just the same: `%c` is still treated as `char`, not `wchar_t`. So instead you need to use `%lc` to format a wide character. And since your strings are ASCII you may as well use `printf`. For example:

```
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8"));
    wchar_t chr = L'┐';
    printf("%lc\n", chr);
}
```